# Prevent Double (or more) post in Django

Tags: python, django, session, post

I'm working on a site built in django, but i'm having a little trouble, in multiple parts im getting double (sometimes 3 or 4) post, for example im submitting a form where you need to save a contact, but when the page reloads im getting 2, 3 or 4 of the same contact. The difference in time is about 0.5 secs. of each other.

I tried to code a little solution like this:

```
def not_double_post(request):
    session_data = request.session.get('post_data', None)
    session_new_data = '-'.join([str(request.user.username),
                                 str(int(time.time()))])
    if session_data is None:
        request.session['post_data'] = session_new_data
        return True
    else:
        current_user = request.user.username
        current_time = int(time.time())
        session_post_user = session_data.split('-')[0]
        session_post_time = session_data.split('-')[1]
        if current_user == session_post_user:
            time_difference = current_time - int(session_post_time)
            if time_difference > 10:
                request.session.pop('post_data')
                request.session['post_data'] = ''.join([str(current_user),
                                                     str(int(time.time()))])
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True
```

On each request.method == 'POST' i check this function, store the user and time when the operation has made in session, if the operation user are the same, and the time difference is less than 10 seconds, is an invalid post.

(I'm also setting the attribute of the button to disabled when the user clicks)

But im getting double post with this. I dont know if this really works like i expect, but it would be good to take another point of view (or another recommendation to achieve this).

Thanks!

==== UDATE views.py =====

```
def cancel_invoice(request, pk):
if not_double_post(request):
    order = PaymentOrder.objects.get(pk=pk)
    order.cancelled_date = datetime.date.today()
    folio = order.invoice_sat.comp_folio
    serie = order.invoice_sat.comp_serie
    rfc_receptor = order.client.rfc
    folio = folio
    soap_doc = '<soapenv:Envelope ' \
               'xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" ' \
               'xmlns:xsaf="http://xsafilereceiver.webservices.manager.xsa.tralix.com">' \
               '<soapenv:Header/>' \
               '<soapenv:Body>' \
               '<xsaf:cancelaCFD>' \
               '<xsaf:in0>' + serie + '</xsaf:in0>' \
               '<xsaf:in1>' + folio + '</xsaf:in1>' \
               '<xsaf:in2>' + settings.IENTC_RFC + '</xsaf:in2>' \
               '<xsaf:in3>' + settings.API_KEY + '</xsaf:in3>' \
               '</xsaf:cancelaCFD>' \
               '</soapenv:Body>' \
               '</soapenv:Envelope>'

    factura_client = ServiceClient(settings.API_CANCEL_URL)
    invoice_status = factura_client.service.cancelaCFD(__inject={'msg': soap_doc})
    if invoice_status:
        order.invoice_sat.invoice_status = 0
        order.amount_to_pay = None
        order.invoice_sat.save()
        order.save()
        if serie == settings.INVOICE_SERIE:
            order.client.balance = order.client.balance + order.total
        else:
            order.client.balance = order.client.balance - order.total
        order.client.save()
        comment = request.POST.get('comment', None)
        if comment.strip() != '' and comment is not None:
            cancelled_folio = folio
            CANCEL_EVENT = 'Administración'
            CANCEL_INVOICE_TITLE = 'Cancelación de Factura #%s' % \
                                   str(cancelled_folio)
            cancel_type, created = EventType.objects.get_or_create(
                name=CANCEL_EVENT)
            Event(
                client=order.client,
                register_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                event_type=cancel_type,
                event=CANCEL_INVOICE_TITLE,
                additional_comments=comment.strip(),
                created_by=request.user
            ).save()
            mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill(settings.MADRILL_API_KEY)
            message = dict()
            message['subject'] = 'Cancelación de Factura'
            message['from_email'] = 'crm@ientc.com'
            message['from_name'] = 'CRM IENTC'
            message['text'] = CANCEL_INVOICE_TITLE
            message['to'] = [
                {
                    'email': 'conta@ientc.com',
                    'name': 'Contabilidad IENTC',
                    'type': 'to'
                }
            ]
            result = mandrill_client.messages.send(
                message=message, async=False)
            print result
        return response_json("OK", 200)
    else:
        return response_json("ERROR CANCELANDO FACTURA", 400)
else:
    return response_json("OK", 200)
```

In this particular POST im making a soap call, but also i'm having troubles on other POST with simple code. Thanks!

Comment: Are the duplicate posts caused by double-clicking on the submit button on your UI? If so, you could simply disable the button when it's clicked with javascript.

Comment: No, i'm setting button attr to disabled when the user clicks. I think this is not triggering the double post.

Comment: Please post your view to create a post.

Comment: I've just uploaded my view.. @TheDjangoNinja